# Split data frame in python based on one parameter shape

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, split

I have a data frame which is like the following :

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import warnings

df_input = pd.read_csv('combine_input.csv', delimiter=',')
df_output = pd.read_csv('combine_output.csv', delimiter=',')
```

[image: Dataframe]

In this data frame, there are many repeated rows for example the first row is repeated more than 1000 times, and so on for the other rows

when I plot the time distribution I got that figure which shows that the frequency of the time parameter

```py
df_input.plot(y='time',kind = 'hist',figsize=(10,10))
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

[image: Time distribution]

My question is how can I take the data only in the following  red rectangular for example at time = 0.006 and frequency = 0.75 1e6 ( check the following pic )

[image: Red rectangular]

Comment: please provide your data as **text**

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: done. let me know if it's still not clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note: InPlace of target you have to write time as your column name Is time,or change column name to target**

```
def calRows(df,x,y):
#df For consideration
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df.target[df.target<=x])
minCount = len(df1)
targets = df1.target.unique()
for i in targets:
    count = int(df1[df1.target == i].count())
    if minCount > count:
        minCount = count

if minCount > y:
    minCount = int(y)
return minCount
```

**You have To pass your data frame, x-intercept of the graph, y-intercept of graph to calRows(df,x,y) function which will return the number of rows to take for each target.**

```
rows = CalRows(df,6,75)
print(rows)
```

takeFeatures(df,rows,x) function will take dataframe, rows (result of first function), x-intercept of graph and will return you the final dataframe.

```
def takeFeatures(df,rows,x):
finalDf = pd.DataFrame(columns = df.columns)
df1 = df[df.target<=x]
targets = df1.target.unique()

for i in targets:
    targeti = df1[df1.target==i]
    sample = targeti.sample(rows)
    finalDf = pd.concat([finalDf,sample])

return finalDf
```

Calling takeFeature() Function

```
final = takeFeatures(df,rows,6)
print(final)
```

**Your Final DataFrame will have the Values ThatYou expected in Graph**
And After Plotting this final dataframe you will get like this graph
[image]

Comment: Thank you Manjothi for your help I really appreciate that. I am almost a beginner at python. actually, I tried your idea and it seems it works but not every time. for example, I have two files input and output files, and when I try your code with the input file alone it works perfectly I think but with some other files that have the same distribution and same structure of the data the function callrow always return 1 only

Comment: You Know I am also a beginner, but I like Your question and so tried to solve it